# Tkinter variable problems?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am having trouble calculating a value through a function with the "click" of the button I created called "Submit". I created two Radio Buttons to select which value of pi to let the user choose. The two different values that the user could choose were 3.14, the rational abrupt version of pi that most textbooks use to compute the area and circumference of a circle, and the irrational, regular version of pi, 3.1415... and so on. I created the pi variable outside of the function that calculates the final value through the expression that is linked to the radio buttons. When one radio button is selected, the variable "value" then has the value for that radio button sent to it. I can then manipulate the variable "value" and choose logically in my code to set the variable "pi" equal to the rational or irrational version pi. I am having trouble using the pi variable inside one of my functions. I know that I have to use global variables and I tried to, but I just couldn't get it to work. I am also having trouble receiving input from the Radio Buttons. I am 13 and new to python and coding as a whole:

```
from Tkinter import *
import cmath
import math   

top = Toplevel()
top.wm_title("Circumference")
#top.geometry("500x500")
space = Label(top, text=" ")
space.pack()
global finalans
global pi
finalans = StringVar()

#Pi Choose
value = IntVar()

Radiobutton(top, text="Rational Pi - 3.14", variable=value, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(top, text="Irrational Pi - 3.1415...", variable=value, value=2).pack(anchor=W)

if value == 1:
    pi = 3.14

if value == 2:
    pi = math.pi


s = Label(top, text=" ")
s.pack()

h = Label(top, text="Radius")
h.pack()



def Answer():
    firstval = int(e.get())
    finalans.set("Answer: " + str(2 * pi * firstval))



#First Entry
e = Entry(top)
e.pack()
e.focus_set()


add2 = Button(top, text="Submit", width=10, command=Answer)
add2.pack()

#Final Answer
answer = Label(top, textvariable=finalans)
answer.pack()
```

When I run this, I want the label to display "2 * pi * firstval". I keep on getting errors about how the "pi" variable reference in the function "Answer" is unsolved and there is nothing it is referencing to it. I stated at the beginning of my code that the "pi" variable is a global value. In addition to the trouble with global variables in my program, I am not able to receive input from my Radio Buttons and I need help with them. If anyone has the time, please help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your globals inside the function:

```
def Answer():
    global pi, e, finalans
    firstval = int(e.get())
    finalans.set("Answer: " + str(2 * pi * firstval))
```

(This is not required in Python 2, so you probably use Python 3?)

Comment: I use version Python 2

Comment: @RohanK., please add the actual error you get to your question. (I get no error with Python 2.7.)

Comment: @RohanK.: Then kindly put it here as an answer & close this question as answered. Thanks